# UISearchBar to filter custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to filter custom UITableViewCells, based on one of the UILabels present in the cell.

All of the data is parsed from remote JSON, which has the model locally named `Item` and currently I am displaying the following in each cell successfully:

```
var titleLabel = UILabel()
var descriptionLabel = UILabel()
```

Also defined in my `ItemTableViewCell` class is:

```
  func set(product: Item) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.titleLabel.text = item.title
            self?.descriptionLabel.text = item.listPrice
        }
    }
```

These are called within my main View Controller, to which I have added a searchBar successfully and is visible within the app:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ItemsListViewController: UIViewController {

    var items = [Items]()
    var itemsSearch: [Items] = []
    var tableView = UITableView()
    var searchController = UISearchController()

    struct Cells {
        static let itemCell = "ItemCell"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTableView()
        configureSearchController()
    }

    func configureSearchController() {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search items"
        definesPresentationContext = true
        var isSearchBarEmpty: Bool {
          return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
        }
    }

    func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        setTableViewDelegates()
        tableView.rowHeight = 100
        tableView.pin(to: view)
        tableView.register(itemTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: Cells.itemCell)
    }

    func setTableViewDelegates() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension itemsListViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.itemCell) as! itemTableViewCell
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.set(item: item)
        return cell
    }
}

extension ItemsListViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
  }
}
```

How can I filter these cells so say for instance a user searches for "Food", the only items which return would be ones which have a cell `titleLabel = "food"`?

I've tried to implement a function similar to the below, however it fails to achieve what I am after:

```
  func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, category:  = nil) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.productCell) as! ProductTableViewCell
      productsSearch = products.filter { (cell: cell) -> Bool in
        return products.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
      }
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not filter TableViewCells. You have to filter your model data and instead of using `UISearchResultsUpdating` you should use `UISearchBarDelegate`

I have modified your code, check it.

```
class ItemsListViewController: UIViewController {

    var items = [Items]()
    var itemsSearch: [Items] = []

    var filterActive = false
    var tableView = UITableView()
    var searchController = UISearchController()

    struct Cells {
        static let itemCell = "ItemCell"
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureTableView()
        configureSearchController()
    }

    func configureSearchController() {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search items"
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        definesPresentationContext = true

    }

    func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        setTableViewDelegates()
        tableView.rowHeight = 100
        tableView.pin(to: view)
        tableView.register(itemTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: Cells.itemCell)
    }

    func setTableViewDelegates() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ItemsListViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filterActive ? itemsSearch.count : items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.itemCell) as! itemTableViewCell

        let item = filterActive ?  itemsSearch[indexPath.row] : items[indexPath.row]
        cell.set(item: item)
        return cell
    }
}

extension ItemsListViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)  {
        filterItems(text: searchController.searchBar.text)
    }
    func filterItems(text: String?) {
        guard let text = text else {
            filterActive = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        }

        self.itemsSearch = self.items.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
                return item.title.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
        })
        filterActive = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

// Edited Version 


     func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
                searchBar.text = nil
                filterActive = false
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've marked this correct as it answers my original question - thank you.

Follow up Q, how can I clear the data displayed once I've done a search? I can now filter the items, but the default state of the VC will be stuck on the result of the filtering, even after cancelling the search

Comment: Implement searchBarCancelButtonClicked method of UISearchBarDelegate, I have also edited my answer.

Comment: That also worked! Only issue is if I tap search then immediately tap cancel then no list loads

Comment: Yes I understood Please implement searchBarCancelButtonClicked method as I did and it will call when you tapped searchBar cancel button and reset the tableView

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the wrong way.

1. You should not filter the *cells*, but instead filter the *model* (e.g. add and remove entries to the table view data source)
2. Then call `reloadData` - this will then access the filtered model (in `cellForRowAt` and create only the filtered amount of (visible) cells
3. To improve, use a diffable data source

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I don't think I can change my data source as it comes from remote JSON which cannot be stored locally